# "this" keyword in meteor template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm working through Discover Meteor and have come upon some code I'm not quite clear on. Here is my template and related js

```
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
      <p>
        submitted by {{author}}
        {{#if ownPost}}<a href="{{postEditPath this}}">Edit</a>{{/if}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <a href="{{postPagePath this}}" class="discuss btn">Discuss</a>
  </div>
</template>

Template.postItem.helpers({
  ownPost: function(){
    return this.userId == Meteor.userId();
  },
  domain: function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.url;
    return a.hostname;
  }
});
```

In general I'm a little unclear on how "this" is working in the context of this js. I understand "this" to be the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of per [the quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html), but I'm not really understanding this chain in the context of how meteor is implementing it. Just looking at the code, I'd expect this.userId to be null. Can someone help me or point me at some docs that explain how "this" works in Meteor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised this question isn't asked more often because it is not obvious or clearly documented.

Recommended reading:

- [Meteor templates and data contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)
- [The live templates section of the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtmltemplates)

The above articles should explain the situation pretty clearly, but here's the quick version:

The context ("this") inside of a helper is the context of the template instance. You can give a template a context directly like this:

```
{{> postItem myItem}}
// The context is now myItem. "this" inside of a helper is the myItem document.
```

or indirectly like so:

```
{{#each posts}}
// The context is now a post. "this" inside of a helper is a post document.
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks David. That clarified things quite a big, but I'm still a bit confused as far as this specific scenario. userId would stem from the user that is logged in, via the accounts package for meteorite. I don't see anywhere where we're setting that data context. If anything I'd expect the data context to be set to a post rather than a user. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Which chapter/section is this in the book?

Comment: The context for that helper is a post. All posts have a userId. Therefore `this.userId` is valid. In this case it happens to be the owner of the post. You can prove that a post has a userId by calling `Posts.findOne()` in your browser console. It's added as part of the `post` method when creating new posts in the "pick out the whitelisted keys" section. `Meteor.userId()` is a function which returns the id of the currently logged in user. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: Crystal. I was just looking at it from the wrong angle. Thanks David!

Comment: Both links from _Recommended Reading_ seem to be broken.